# Setting a value in DataTable fires SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `listbox1` which is bound to a `DataTable` named `Notes`, the line on which I set value in cell of DataTable changes `listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1` then again set `listBox1.SelectedIndex` to original value and finishes. Hence that line calls `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event twice.

Instead it should not even call that event. How to solve this problem?

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        dataSet11.Notes.Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex]["Text"] = richTextBox1.Text; 
        //this line fires listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event
        //with listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
        //then it changes listBox1.SelectedIndex back to original value before complete execution, and calls the even again
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trigger boolean field for this:

```
private TextBox_OntextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.supressEvents = true;
    //Do your stuff here
    this.supressEvents = false;
}

private void ListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (this.supressEvents)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily remove the SelectedIndexChanged handlers

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
  if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
      dataSet11.Notes.Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex]["Text"] = richTextBox1.Text; 
      //this line fires listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event
      //with listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
      //then it changes listBox1.SelectedIndex back to original value before complete execution, and calls the even again
  }
  listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Comment: Why it didn't came in my head... Thanks